# ResourceBundle can't be found in jar

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have a problem when I export my project to a jar. The ResourceBundles work fine when I run the project in Eclipse, but not from the jar. I exported it as Export -> jar file.

I start the jar in (Windows) cmd -> java -jar %projectName%.jar. The ResourceBundles are:

- Eclipse: %projectName% -> src -> language
- In the jar: folder language.

And I load it this way:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("language.Language", currentLocale)
```

I looked at so many other questions about this on Stackoverflow and their problem was always that they didn't provide a path from the root. I have no idea why this isn't working. I tried putting these .properties files at root too...

Note: the class that manages these bundles/locales is also in the same packages.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: maybe some extra information, I get the Strings this way:

```
public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return ResourceBundle.getBundle("language.Language", currentLocale)
                    .getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return "KEY " + key + " NOT FOUND !";
        }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle
 for base name language.Language, locale nl_be
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at language.LanguageModel.getString(LanguageModel.java:33)
        at cli.class.method(class.java:35)
        at main.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

The properties:

```
Language_en_US.properties
Language_fr_FR.properties
Language_nl_BE.properties
....
```

Comment: print the stack trace of the exception and paste it in your question. And paste the result of `jar -tf yourjar.jar`

Comment: Trace added, your command gives:Unrecognized option: -tf
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: The command is `jar -tf jarFile.jar`, and not `java -jar -tf jarFile.jar`. But The stack trace was suffficient to identify the problem. See my answer.

Comment: It says "jar" is not recognised.

Comment: Put the JDK/bin directory in your PATH environment variable. And check my answer. It answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locale you pass in argument to `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` has its country set to "be". It should be set to "BE" instead.

You should also consider using properties files with only the langage code suffix, and have one backup bundle without suffix at all:

- Language : will be used at last resort
- Language_nl : will be used when the language is "nl"
- Language_nl_BE : should override the translations from Language_nl if they're specific to Belgium

Comment: I set currentLocale = new Locale("nl_BE"); So it is in capitals?

Comment: Check the javadoc of Locale. It should be `new Locale("nl", "BE")`. The error message says: *Can't find bundle
 for base name language.Language, locale nl_be*. So no, it's not in uppercase.